# Missing references in LightSwitch Beta 1 autogen code

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying out the new LightSwitch beta 1 and getting the following error when I try to build.  Not much special - I tried to create a new screen based off of data sources from an existing database.  Of course, there's no place to add references.

Error   5   The type or namespace name 'DomainServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  [...]DataClientImplementation.cs    19  37  ClientGenerated

Anyone else playing with this new stuff?

If Microsoft is smart, they'll be monitoring StackOverflow as well and can ask followup questions of me to narrow down the issue ;-)

OK, by a suggestion by Jeff below:

Prior to the uninstall of the existing RIA:

System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework.xml
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData.xml
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.xml
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.xml

After reinstalling from the LightSwitch iso:

**Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.dll
Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.xml**
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework.xml
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData.xml
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.xml
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll
System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.xml

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534611/lightswitch-beta-1-looking-for-sql-express-instead-of-full-sql-instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the Install failed to properly install Ria Services.

On the install disk, goto WCU\Silverlight\ and try installing riaservices manually.

The Dll's should be located:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server

or

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\RIA Services\v1.0\Libraries\Server

Comment: OK!  tried to comment here, but line-breaks were stripped, so I updated the post.  Thanks.  Testing now ...

Comment: It's not totally working yet, but those references errors are gone.